# Grub not booting windows boot loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Im dual booting Ubuntu/Windows.

So first of all booting windows by selecting the windows boot loader from UEFI works fine.

Im using EFI for both bootloaders.

Booting Ubuntu from grub also works fine, just booting windows from grub does not. The screen just instantly returns me to the grub screen without any error.

This started after I re-partitioned another hard drive from my laptop (running Arch) and accidentally ran update-grub by auto-completion while it was connected. This created a boot entry for arch, which I removed by running grub-update again after disconnecting that drive.

I added paging=1 and debug=all to grub.cfg to try and debug the boot sequence but didnt find any errors.

Has anyone got any ideas? Im happy to provide any details needed. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Is Windows fast start up off? Windows will turn it back on with updates, which may be in back ground when you boot Windows from UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @oldfred its off already

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair